# Is there is any solution for connecting client and server in socket program in node js

Tags: node.js, sockets, server, connection, client

I am trying to connect socket client and server but not able. This is my server expServer.js

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'css')));

io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
console.log("new user");
socket.emit("msg","hello");

});
http.listen(8000,()=>{
console.log("server is running at port 8000");
});
```

another file index.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
   <script defer src="Client/client.js"></script>
    <script defer src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <img class="logo" src="logo.png" >
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="message left">harry:hi how are you?</div>
            <div class="message right">rohan:vai i am good.How about you?</div>
        </div>
        <div class="send">
            <form action="#" id="send-contaner">
                <input type=" text" name="messageid" id="messageid">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

another file client.js

```
var socket =  io("http://localhost:8000");
   socket.on("msg", data =>{
console.log(data);
   });
```

I am not able to connect client and server. I got error "Uncaught ReferenceError:io is not define"

I hope somebody have solution.

Comment: In your HTML, you need to include the Socket.io script before you include the client.js script.

Answer (score 0):

Your script sequence:

```
<script defer src="Client/client.js"></script>
<script defer src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Try changing the sequence to

```
<script defer src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script defer src="Client/client.js"></script>
```

For your reference you can check this:
https://github.com/abhishekpankar/socket-io